# wp_title() empty on a static front page

Tags: filters, title, frontpage

I'm trying to use `wp_title()` to create a heading for my pages, but I'm using a static front page and, while all of the other pages render the title properly, the front page won't.

This is what I'm working with:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <h1><?php wp_title("", true); ?></h1>
    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
        <div class="pagecontent">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile ?>   
</div>
```

Initially I thought that the front page might be drawing from `index.php`, so I added the same code snippet in there – but, no such luck, the same thing gets rendered – an empty `h1` tag.

What's going on here? I want the title of the page to show up in the h1 tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [wp_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) is for the html title tags in your websites head section.

It's not for outputting a title.  [Use the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), or [get_the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title),

Comment: Thank you! I replaced `wp_title()` with `the_title()` and everything looks good now.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [source of `wp_title()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L506) you will see that there is not output planned for a static front page.

Use `the_title()` for visual output as @Chris_O suggested. But for the title in the `<head>` section you have to filter `wp_title()` and fill it if it is empty.

Sample code ([download from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/3086243)):

```
// Hook in very late, let the theme fix it first.
add_filter( 'wp_title', 't5_fill_static_front_page_title', 100 );

/**
 * Fill empty front page title if a static page is set.
 *
 * @wp-hook wp_title
 * @param   string $title Existing title
 * @return  string
 */
function t5_fill_static_front_page_title( $title )
{
    // another filter may have fixed this already.
    if ( '' !== $title or ! is_page() or ! is_front_page() )
    {
        return $title;
    }

    $page_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
    $page    = get_page( $page_id );

    if ( ! $page or '' === $page->post_title )
    {
        $title = get_option( 'blogname' );
    }
    else
    {
        $title = $page->post_title;
    }

    // We don’t know if there is any output after the title, so we cannot just
    // add the separator. We use an empty space instead.
    return "$title ";
}
```