# How to change tag Title to its name?

Tags: tags, title

i have previously asked it in stackoverflow, but there was no answer!
I wish to change the title of Tags pages of my wordpress blog. What I want to do is to keep the Tag name as it's title only.

For example: If a tag name is "Wordpress Tag Pages Tutorial" then that tag should have the same title "Wordpress Tag Pages Tutorial" instead of "Blog Name - Wordpress Tag Pages Tutorial" so what to change in this code? I have tried but showing errors like only variables name in wordpress title.

```
<title>
<?php if (is_home () ) { bloginfo('name'); }elseif ( is_category() ) {
single_cat_title(); echo ' - ' ; bloginfo('name'); }
elseif (is_single() ) { single_post_title();}
elseif (is_page() ) { bloginfo('name'); echo ': '; single_post_title();}
else { wp_title('',true); } ?>
```

please see this screen-cast [i.stack.imgur.com/Ai9JU.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai9JU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use …

```
if ( is_tax( 'post_tag' ) )
    echo single_term_title();
```

I would just call a naked `wp_title()` and change that title per filter. See [example 1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58080/73), [2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52157/73) and [3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72493/73).